# Terraform and Elastic Beanstalk with multiple Environments under the same Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

I'm using Terraform to create an Elastic Beanstalk Application and two associated Environments, and am having some difficulties with the setup. Specifically, I have two Terraform configurations for my two environments, production and staging, and an Elastic Beanstalk module. Something like this:

```
├── environments
│   ├── production
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── staging
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── variables.tf
└── modules
    └── elastic_beanstalk
        ├── main.tf
        └── variables.tf
```

With Elastic Beanstalk, the convention is Application > Environment > Application Version, so the EB Application would be something like "elastic_beanstalk", and then there would be EB Environments for production and staging.

**The problem**: I don't know how to handle the EB Application creation with TF, because it needs to be shared between the two TF environments. If I handle the EB Application creation inside of the module called from the staging config, then calling the module from the production config throws errors because it doesn't recognize that the EB Application is already created and should be used. Maybe some sort of global config that handles this and is output so it's available in the module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terraform doesn't typically handle some of the versioned resources that AWS handles, instead it's typically easier to create completely decoupled resources that represent those stages. This is particularly true for things like AWS' API Gateway which has a concept of stages that Terraform doesn't handle well at all.

With Elastic Beanstalk you could choose to ignore the environment function that EB offers and instead just create a separate application and environment for each of your production and staging environments so a very basic module might look something like this:

```
variable "environment" {}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "application" {
  name        = "my-application-${var.environment}"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "environment" {
  name                = "my-application-${var.environment}"
  application         = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.application.name}"
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.3 running Go 1.4"
}
```

You could then call the module the same but passing in a different environment name to get a completely separate EB application in AWS that happens to be named by the environment.

Alternatively, if you wanted to stick to EB's environment model you could define the application separately and then deploy just the environment at the environment level.

So in this case your layout might look something like:

```
.
├── application
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── environments
│   ├── production
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── staging
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── variables.tf
└── modules
    └── elastic_beanstalk_environment
        ├── main.tf
        └── variables.tf
    └── elastic_beanstalk_application
        ├── main.tf
        └── variables.tf
```

And you would have to apply the `application` directory first before deploying the environment directories later.

Without having any experience of Elastic Beanstalk I'd probably lean towards the first model because it simplifies how I would deploy things with Terraform, knowing that if I apply the staging environment and things are fine then applying the production environment is also going to work well. With the second model there's a possibility that someone applies changes to the `application` after the staging environment has been applied and then you are potentially deploying changes to production that haven't been deployed to staging.

With API Gateway and Lambda, which also support some form of internal versioning, I have found it's generally better to ignore this versioning and create completely distinct resources and use Terraform modules and symlinked configuration to keep things in line properly.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response! I chose to do it the latter way, to stay consistent with the EB environment model. If anyone is looking for details, I can definitely provide them.